# 2017 VWPassat RLINE 1.8T

Tags: electrical, vw, electronic-control-module

I basically put some acidic and corrosive fluids inside of my windshield wiper reservoir tank didn’t notice it until a few weeks later and plenty of trips, using my fluid and cleaning my windows that the wires began to corrode through the plastic coating around it, and the wire the mesh Two weeks after that which makes it some total of roughly a month and some change I’m riding to the store two minutes down the road and the part in between my hood where the wires run to was on fire,I then cut off the rest of the washer, sprayer nozzle and put electrical tape on it and pull the fuse. Well now about two weeks after that check engine light came on and I know it was my problem please someone help me how do I get fix this before it really spreads through the ECU?

Comment: The windshield wiper and washer reservoir, pump and wiring are completely separate from the engine electronics. However, if damage occurs to any wiring related to engine sensors from this mistake, you might have to carefully trace by visual and hand inspection, where damage occurred. You should decode stored errors, either from Autozone or other auto parts store providing free readings. Refrain from any suggestions if they're not ASE certified in vehicle repairs. Copy error codes and find definitions online to start. If uncomfortable with repairs, you have options; repair shop, friends, etc.